# Como remover uma frase dentro de um arquivo TXT

Tags: php, php-7, txt

Opa galerinha,
Estou necessitando de um help, quero remover uma KEY dentro de um arquivo TXT porem não estou conseguindo.

keys.txt:

```
aLZkGWPXTLVdpVl
w17AzQZIy22soy9
rAcEiWHwopYz2Pk
uKPhbc0Xok5a2aO
```

meu codigo .php:

```
<?php
    $texto = "w17AzQZIy22soy9";

    $linha_n = $texto;
    echo $linha_n;

    //Ler o arquivo
    $linhas = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents("youtube.txt"));

    // Abre o arquivo e coloca o ponteiro no final
    $arquivo = fopen('keys.txt','r+');
    if ($arquivo) {
        while(true) {
        $linha = fgets($arquivo);
        if ($linha==null) break;


    // Busca o conteudo que vai ser alterado
    if(preg_match("/$linha_n/", $linha)) {
    $string =+ str_replace("$linha_n", "", $linha);
    } else {
    // Vai colocando tudo numa nova string
    $string =+ $linha;
    }
    }
    // Move o ponteiro para o inicio pois o ftruncate() nao fara isso
    rewind($arquivo);

    // Apagar todo o conteudo
    ftruncate($arquivo, 0);

    // reescreve o conteudo do arquivo
    if (!fwrite($arquivo, $string)) die('Não foi possível atualizar o arquivo.');
    echo 'Arquivo atualizado com sucesso';
    fclose($arquivo);
    }

?>
```

Poderiam me ajudar galerinha?
**obs: ja pesquisei aqui na comunidade e em outros forums nao e encontrei a solucao!**

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema com a tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Código comentado.**

```
$search = "w17AzQZIy22soy9";
$filename="keys.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$new_contents = "";
if (strpos($contents, $search) !== false) { // se o arquivo contem $search
    $contents_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);
    foreach ($contents_array as &$record) {    // para cada linha
        if (strpos($record, $search) !== false) { // se encontramos a linha correta
            continue; // encontramos a linha a ser excluída - portanto, não adicionaremos ao novo conteúdo.
        } else {
            $new_contents .= $record . "\r"; // não é a linha que queremos excluir, então a mantemos
        }
    }
    $new_contents=trim($new_contents);
    file_put_contents($filename, $new_contents); // salve os registros no arquivo
    echo json_encode("Arquivo atualizado com sucesso!");
}
else {
    echo json_encode($search ." não existe no arquivo!");
}
```

> PHP_EOL - Disponível a partir do PHP 5.0.2

> Versões mais antigas `$contents_array = explode("\n", $contents);`

Comment: @GustavoAlves, você testou o que sugeri no comentário acima?

Comment: @GustavoAlves, mas vi o arquivo txt no meu servidor e a linha foi excluida.

Comment: resposta aceita significa exito. Retiro os comentários com links

Comment: resultado final: consegui arrumar, o erro em si era a VPS que limitava edição de arquivos, comprei outra VPS... Obrigado por ajudar!